# Social Engine logo image size change

Tags: css, height, socialengine, graphical-logo

I'm trying to change the top image for a social engine site. I can do it in Chrome when I inspect element but when I try to change it in the custom css section of the control panel it doesn't make the change. I'm trying to change min height from 40 to 70px.

Here's the code and a link to the page:

http://phillyspecials.socialengine.com/

```
 #header #logo img {
      display: block;
      max-width: 300px;
      min-height: 70px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up sticking the CSS in the header HTML file under templates, this did the job

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted shows max-height, change max to min and you should be good.

Comment: I just changes it to the above and there's still no change on the link
I can get it to change in the developer tools on my browser but it just doesn't work from the admin. Is there a way to edit the actual CSS file either using FTP to download or admin?

Comment: Looks like your site is down at the moment. Are you using Wordpress? I think you were. If so, you can change the css directly but Wordpress (and I) recommends you make a child theme instead. Here's a link to doing that: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: Also, this is not usually recommended, but if all else fails you can always put !important after the css value: http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/